# Can't create a mysql connection

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I want to connect a mysql database to crystal reports 2013. I followed this [sap tutorial](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/02/18/quick-start-guide-to-mysql-database-and-sap-crystal-reports-2013/). Everything is right but in step 6 when I want to create an ODBC connection from Crystal Reports I can't due to the error:

The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you create a 32-bit DSN, not 64-bit.
Crystal Reports Designer is a 32-bit application.

Comment: I uninstalled the 64 bits ODBC controller and I installed the 32 bit, but when I go to control panel -> ODBC data sources to create a mysql odbc controller it only appears sqlserver. My Windows 7 is an 64 bit operating system. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Perhaps you are confusing "controller" with "driver".
In any case, follow the instructions (Google instructions for your particular ODBC driver) of how to add a 32-bit DSN.

Comment: Thanks for answers. The issue is fixed. After installing the MySQL ODBC controller according the tutorial I can't display the driver necessary to create the System DSN. The solution is this tutorial: https://syntaxdrops.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/installing-and-configuring-mysql-32-bit-odbc-driver-on-a-64-bit-operating-system/